# SWI-Prolog list manipulation

Tags: prolog, primes

As part of a program I'm writing I need to make sure a variable does not equal any number that is the result of multiplying 2 numbers in a given list. For example: I've got a list Primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11] and I need to make sure that X does not equal any two of those numbers multiplied together such as 6 (2*3) or 55 (5*11) etc...

The code I have is as follows:

```
    list(Numbers):-
           Numbers = [X, Y, Sum],
           between(3,6,Y),
           between(3,6,X),
           Primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11],
           Sum is X+Y,
           (Code i need help with)
```

The above code wiill type out results of [3,3,6], [4,3,7], [5,3,8] and so on. Now what I want is to be able to identify when sum is equal to a prime * prime and exclude that from the results. Something like Sum \= prime * prime. However, I don't know how to loop through the elements in Prime in order to multiply two elements together and then do that for all element in the list.

Hope this makes sense; im not great at explaining things.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is inefficient, but easy to code:

```
...
forall((nth(I,Primes,X),nth(J,Primes,Y),J>I), Sum =\= X*Y).
```

I think you could use that loop to initialize a list of precomputed factors, then use memberchk/2.

In SWI-Prolog use nth1/3 instead of nth/3